# How to avoid double refresh for a new change in a service worker

Tags: service-worker, workbox

Let's say I have a service worker installation directly in my `main.js` (I am not waiting `load` event or anything).

Let's say I have a file called login.js which I change so often and I don't use a hash fingerprint for it in the build process.

When I change the code in login.js and built it, My service worker also changes because I use workbox and its `injectManifest` still works with file contents and if something changes, regenerates manifest. So service worker gets changed too.

The bad thing that happens is when an user refreshes the page, the new changes don't get shown. I use `skipWaiting`. The reason changes don't get shown, is that

1. there might be old service worker returning the old one before installing the new service worker takes place.
2. the new service worker will get activated immediately but fetch listener for it won't be called. (I don't want to use clients.claim() as it's kind of tricky)

I saw [how Jake Archibald does it](https://github.com/jakearchibald/wittr/compare/task-update-notify...update-interaction#diff-18fb79d8e23051a8d357ce7db95ff2f0) and he programmatically refreshes the page after the user refreshes the page which means two refreshes take place. I only want one refresh.